# Lowering UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I've been trying to put UITableView a little bit lower because of a modal panel that I'm displaying in top of the screen in my iphone application.

I've tried resizing the navigationBar (altough at the end I want to hide it) with a hope that it'd push the UITableView - although without luck.
Then I've tried setting the frame and bounds rects of the UITableView manually, but it didn't work either.

Could someone more experianced show me the right way to do it?
Thanks,

Comment: Are you setting up the view programmatically or via a nib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I create `UITableView`s programatically, I never put them in `UITableViewController`s, but in classical `UIViewController`s where I define the tableView's `frame` on first display. That allows for greater flexibility.

Read this thread for more info: http://www.skylarcantu.com/blog/2009/09/24/dont-use-uitableviewcontroller-really/

Comment: This is probably the best approach I've seen, I'll take a look on that - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `contentInsets` property of the tableview to lower it how much you want.

Comment: Yes, thanks - actually this turns out to be pretty good idea - I've tried it a bit before you wrote it here, but with my current setup it lowers not only UITableView but also all the other stuff - this is probably because in UITableViewController, view == tableView.